# Mysql from sum one table column subtract sum of another table column

Tags: mysql

Have 2 tables. In both tables exists columns for points and Id of user.
Want to sum all points for particular user in one table, then to sum in another and subtract from total of one table, total of another table.
Have 2 solutions (and also here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f040a2/1 placed my testings). Please advice which is better for performance.

The first solution. Very clear and seems without "problems"

```
SELECT 
( SELECT SUM(`PurchasedPoints`) FROM `first_table` WHERE `Id` = ? ) 
- 
( SELECT SUM(`SpendPoints`) FROM `second_table` WHERE `Id` = ? ) AS `RemainingPaidPoints`
```

Another solution with `LEFT JOIN`. Somewhere read, that `LEFT JOIN` is better for performance than subqueries. But code looks complicated and not sure if it is reasonable to use it.

```
SELECT SUM(`Ft`.`PurchasedPoints`) - `St`.`SpendPoints` AS `RemainingPaidPoints` 
FROM `first_table` `Ft` 

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT SUM(`SpendPoints`) AS `SpendPoints`, `Id` FROM `second_table` WHERE `Id` = ? 
GROUP BY `Id`
) `St` ON `Ft`.`Id` = `St`.`Id` 

WHERE `Ft`.`Id` = ? 

GROUP BY `Ft`.`Id`
```

With both get the same result, but... which is better for performance etc., please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN works with tables, subqueries work with data sets. That's why JOIN is faster than a subquery.

However, in both the queries you are running two separate `SELECT` queries. So performance-wise both are same. And, if you are counting the summation of a particular `id` then you don't need to use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT SUM(`Ft`.`PurchasedPoints`) - SUM(`St`.`SpendPoints`) AS `RemainingPaidPoints` 
FROM `first_table` `Ft` 
LEFT JOIN `second_table` `St`
ON `Ft`.`Id` = `St`.`Id` 
WHERE `Ft`.`user_id` = ?
```

Comment: However just one comment. If for example `first_table` there are multiple rows with the same `Id`, then get incorrect results (duplicate, triplicate etc.)

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't know if it answers your question. If not feel free to comment. But I'll need a little bit more clarification about your test case. Thanks.

Comment: I placed testings http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f040a2/1 But seems with `Join` too many "problems". Seems better just use sub queries  and be sure that can get what is expected

Comment: I did this `SELECT 'Ft'.'id01', 'St'.'id02', 'Ft'.'PurchasedPoints', 'St'.'SpendPoints', 
SUM('Ft'.'PurchasedPoints') - SUM('St'.'SpendPoints') AS 'RemainingPaidPoints' 
FROM 'first_table' 'Ft' 
LEFT JOIN 'second_table' 'St'
ON 'Ft'.'Id01' = 'St'.'Id02' 
WHERE 'Ft'.'Id' = 1;`